# Problem with putting in the right parameters

Tags: javascript

I have problem with putting in the right parameters from an eventListener into a function.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
    <head>
     <title></title>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <script type="text/javascript">         

           window.onload = function() {
            var galleryContainer = document.getElementById('galleryContainer');
            var image = galleryContainer.getElementsByTagName('div');
            //console.log(image);

            var images = new Array();
            images.push(image);

            for(var i = 0; i < images[0].length; i++) {
                images[0][i].addEventListener('click', function() {showImage(this)
                }, false);
               };
           }
    // I dont know with parameter to put into showImage() from the listener.
           function showImage( here is the problem ) {

            var preview = document.getElementById('preview');
            preview.innerhtml = image.innerhtml;
   // I want to put the image into the preview element.

          }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="galleryContainer">
        <div>trams</div>
        <div>trams</div>
        <div>trams</div>
        <div>trams</div>
    </div>
    <div id="preview" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid red"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: pathetic, but its there within his code :)

Comment: I dont know how to get the image element from the eventListener to the function showImage.

Comment: What's the point of the `images` array? You could use the `image` variable from the line before directly in your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
    <head>
     <title></title>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <script type="text/javascript">         

           window.onload = function() {
             var galleryContainer = document.getElementById('galleryContainer');
             var images = galleryContainer.getElementsByTagName('div');
             //console.log(images);

             for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
               images[i].addEventListener('click', showImage, false);
             };
           }
// I dont know with parameter to put into showImage() from the listener.
           function showImage(ev) {
             ev=ev||event; // ev now point to click event object
             var preview = document.getElementById('preview');
             preview.innerHTML = this.innerHTML; // this point to DIV(trams)
           }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="galleryContainer">
        <div>trams1</div>
        <div>trams2</div>
        <div>trams3</div>
        <div>trams4</div>
    </div>
    <div id="preview" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid red"></div>
</body>
```

Working example http://jsfiddle.net/Cp6HJ/

Comment: there is nothing called `innerhtml`, and i don't think his code should need so much change.

Comment: @Saket I made change `innerhtml` to `innerHTML`

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you very much. Can you explain more what the ev=ev||event; does ?

Comment: About ev=ev||event: in my example you register function `showImage` as handler for all `DIV`(tram) object. When click event occur on any DIV(tram) browser call function `showImage` and send one parameter (Event object: can be an any type: MouseEvent...). But some browser do not send this parameter. And in these browsers you can use global `event` object to access event info. Command ev=ev||event mean: if ev is undefined (no parameter sended), then store event object into ev. For your example you can remove this line.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. This was very helpfull.

Comment: @Oscar: Addition `ev=ev||event` is same as `ev=ev||window.event` in this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function() {
        var galleryContainer = document.getElementById('galleryContainer');
        var image = galleryContainer.getElementsByTagName('div');
        //console.log(image);

        var images = new Array();
        images.push(image);

        for(var i = 0; i < images[0].length; i++) {
            var callback = function(item){ return function(){ showImage(item); }; }(images[0][i]);
            images[0][i].addEventListener('click', callback, false);
         };
       };

       function showImage( item ) {
        var preview = document.getElementById('preview');
        preview.innerHTML = item.innerHTML;
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this for the function definition statement :

```
function showImage(image) { 
   ...
}
```

And correction in the inner html statement:
(note the capitalized 'H')

`preview.innerHTML = image.innerHTML;`